# On the definition of uniform stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Consider the differential equation

$x^{\prime}=f(t,x),{\qquad}t\geq0.\tag{1}$

**Definition 1.** If there exists a constant $x^{\ast}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(t,x^{\ast})=0$ for all $t\geq0$, then $x^{\ast}$ is said to be the *equilibrium solution* of **(1)**.

**Definition 2.** A solution $x$ of **(1)** is *uniformly stable* if for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ such that if $x$ is a solution of (1) and $|x(s)-x^{\ast}|<\delta$ for some $s\geq0$, then $|x(t)−x^{\ast}|<\varepsilon$ for all $t{\geq}s$.

Do you think replacing last two of the strict inequalities ($<$) in *Definition 2* with weaker ones ($\leq$) gives an equivalent definition?

Comment: For homogeneous linear equations, the two of these definitions are equivalent, which works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider the homogeneous linear equation

$x^{\prime}=p(t)x,{\qquad}t\geq0.\tag{2}$

Clearly, for this equation $x^{\ast}=0$.
Further, for any given $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$, $x$ is a solution of **(2)** if and only if $\lambda{}x$ is a solution of **(2)** since **(2)** is linear.

We say that **(2)** satisfies the property (P) if for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ such that if $x$ is a solution of **(2)** and $|x(s)|\leq\delta$ for some $s\geq0$, then $|x(t)|\leq\varepsilon$ for all $t{\geq}s$.

Obviously, if **(2)** is uniformly stable, then it satisfies *(P)*.

Now, let **(2)** satisfy *(P)*. Let be $\varepsilon>0$. From *(P)*, we can find $\delta>0$ such that $|{\lambda}x(s)|\leq\delta$ for some $s\geq0$ implies $|{\lambda}x(t)|\leq\varepsilon$ for all $t{\geq}s$, where $\lambda>1$.
Then, $|x(s)|<\delta$ for some $s\geq0$ implies $|x(t)|<\varepsilon$ for all $t{\geq}s$. That is, **(2)** is uniformly stable.